# Retrieve data from sql server compact 4.0 to textbox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have two text boxes in my winform. I would like to enter a userId into first text box, after that by clicking a button display a  User Name   in the second text box properly. The data is stored in sql server compact. Table name is `Users`, and this table contains two columns `UserID` and `UserName`.

With this code I can open a connection and retrieve the first value from the UserName column,

```
SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = D:\Database\Training.sdf");
        try
        {
          cn.Open();
          SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT   UserID, UserName from Users;", cn);
          TrainerNameBox.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
          cn.Close();
       }
       catch
       { 
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the WHERE clause to isolate the username that you want to display

```
 int userID;
 if(!Int32.TryParse(txtUserID.Text, out userID))
 {
      MessageBox.Show("Invalid User ID number");
      return;
 }
 using(SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = D:\Database\Training.sdf"))
 using(SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT UserName from Users WHERE UserID=@id;", cn))
 {
     cn.Open();
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userID);
     object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
     if(result != null)
         TrainerNameBox.Text = result.ToString();
     else
         MessageBox.Show("No user for ID=" + userID.ToString());

 }
```

Notice that `ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row, so you need to remove the UserID field from your query and if, the user is not found, you need to check for a null return.

Applying directly the ToString() method to your ExecuteScalar could raise an exception if your user types an invalid id. There is also the problem to validate the user input. If you type a not numeric value for the user id, the conversion will fail. In this case you need to check the input using Int32.TryParse

Answer (score 2):

[`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns **first column** of the first row. Other columns or rows are ignored.

In your case, your first column is `UserID`. That's why you get first value of this column.

If you want to get `UserName` value, you might need to change your query like;

```
SELECT UserName from Users
```

And looks like you forget to use `WHERE` clause in your query since you want to get `UserName` from `UserID`. You might need to use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlCeConnection` and `SqlCeCommand`.

Full example;

```
using(SqlCeConnection cn = new SqlCeConnection(@"Data Source = D:\Database\Training.sdf"))
using(SqlCeCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
{
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT UserName from Users WHERE UserID = @id";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", (int)txtUserID.Text);
  cn.Open();
  TrainerNameBox.Text = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    Dataset ds = cmd.ExecuteDataset().ToString();
    TrainerNameBox.Text = ds.tables[0].Rows[0][1].toString();
    TrainerIDBox.Text = ds.tables[0].Rows[0][0].toString();
```